# MySQL select column string with LIKE or REGEX based on sub-string with delimiters

Tags: mysql, sql, regex

I have to compare a column value with a user input numbers. The string in the column is in the format `8|5|12|7|`

Now, I need to compare a user input values `2`,`5`,`3` with this column value

When I use LIKE operator as `'%2|%'` I got the output by matching with column value  `|12|`

How do I match the string by using `Regular Expression` or any other way?

Comment: It appears that your `col` column is storing data in an unnormalized format of `8|5|12|7`.  I would recommend that you normalize your database.  Also, your question is a bit unclear.

Comment: why not search `'|' + your_column + '|' LIKE '%|2|%' or '|' + your_column + '|' LIKE '%|5|%' or '|' + your_column + '|' LIKE '%|3|%'` etc.? that way it will match only the exact numbers you want inside the | characters.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand the question correct, then to make sure that you get `2|..` or `..|2|..` or `|2`, you need to add `or` clauses

```
where col like '%|2|%' 
or col like '2|%'
or col like '%|2'
or col='2'
```

Comment: it will not work too.for example '12|5|8'. it will return '2|' but we don't have it really we have '12|'.

Comment: @Naeim No. for `12|5|8` it will not return anything. Notice there is no `%` before `2` in second line.

Comment: the problem is when using this query -"SELECT * 
FROM  `tbl_profile_more` 
WHERE  `interests` LIKE  '%2|%' " i am getting the output with the column  8|6|12|

Comment: @ParthanHugelview add other `like` conditions followed by `OR` as I answered and then check. Also check Dean's regex which should also work for you.

Comment: Note if a column value is just `2` this won't match, however if the value is `2|` it will. Add another `OR` matching the value `2` to correct this - if needed.

Comment: @DeanTaylor - Seconded. Edited. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Something similar to this to test for `2` in this example `12|8|12|5|12|7|2|12|22`

[image: Regular expression visualization]

```
# (^|\|)2(\||$)
# 
# 
# Match the regex below and capture its match into backreference number 1 «(^|\|)»
#    Match this alternative (attempting the next alternative only if this one fails) «^»
#       Assert position at the beginning of the string «^»
#    Or match this alternative (the entire group fails if this one fails to match) «\|»
#       Match the character “|” literally «\|»
# Match the character “2” literally «2»
# Match the regex below and capture its match into backreference number 2 «(\||$)»
#    Match this alternative (attempting the next alternative only if this one fails) «\|»
#       Match the character “|” literally «\|»
#    Or match this alternative (the entire group fails if this one fails to match) «$»
#       Assert position at the end of the string, or before the line break at the end of the string, if any (line feed) «$»
```

`REGEXP "(^|\|)2(\||$)"`

This allows for the column value to just be `2` or `2|anything` or `anything|2` or `first thing|2|end thing`.

Answer (score 0):

By looking your column design, one of the way u can do is `LIKE '%|2|%'`

Comment: it will not work when 2 is start of string ( 2|3|5|8).

Answer (score 0):

It is bad design to build "arrays" in a cell.  Use a separate table.

Anyway, `FIND_IN_SET()` is a function that does the work a lot easier than a regexp.  (But you have to use ',')