# select field with specific data between commas by regex

Tags: mysql, regex

I have a table in MySQL with these data in it

[image]

I want to get rows with "1" in column row1 by regex. How should I do that?

```
([^,]1/)
```

i use this regex but it only return the rows with "1" in first comma

Comment: Against which columns do you want to do the search?

Comment: try `[[:<:]]1[[:>:]]` or `'\b1\b'`

Comment: Get the rows and split them by a comma (e.g. in PHP). Additionally, really see @Strawberry comment.

Comment: potential duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/34217804/4473405

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [FIND_IN_SET()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) function of mysql

```
select * from my_table where FIND_IN_SET('1',row1) > 0
```

Comment: thanks to you for your response. what about the rows that contain 1,2 and not 3 in them?

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
select *
from tbl
where row1 REGEXP '(^|,)1(,|$)'
```

`(^|,)1(,|$)` means (either `begenning` or `,`)1(either `,` or `end`)
[**sql fiddle demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f6c69/14)

Comment: thanks to you for your response. what about the rows that contain 1,2 and not 3 in them?